# How to convert a column in excel to a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

New practicioner in python:

I have an excel(abc.xlsx) table with column "external_id" and I need to read each **external_id** and put in the below code of my python sdk.

```
ps = c.datapoints.retrieve(external_id=["id1", "id2"])
```

How can i do this? I reached till here in reading the excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile('abc.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')
x=[]
x.append(df['external_id'])
```

Giving more clarity:

If i run this command :

```
ps = c.datapoints.retrieve(external_id=["id1", "id2"])
```

I get a table like this:

```
timestamp     id1     id2
22-01-2021     1       2
23-01-2021     5       0
```

and so on...

and now I have a list of ids which I am taking from a excel column, how can I pass the list of values in the above code and get the result for rest of the ids.

Comment: If you want to turn pandas series into a list you can use [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) `df['external_id'].to_list()`

Comment: i get x as [[id1,id2,...]] while my external_id = [id1,id2] is required in this format. So that means I cant put ps = c.datapoints.retrieve(external_id=x)  as there is extra "[]". how can i resolve that?

Comment: if x is a 2D array, with one element (The array you want) You can use `x[0]` to get it.

Comment: it would be helpful if you include a few records on the dataframe in the question, so I can understand what you want better.

Comment: added more explaination on the requirement . please check